# On frequency decay of an integral transform of a function

Tags: real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, laplace-transform

Suppose $f \in C^{\infty}_c((-1,1))$ and assume that there exists constants $a,b>0$ such that
$$ 
\bigg|\int_{\mathbb R} f(t) \,e^{\tau t^2+i\tau t}\,dt\bigg| \leq a\,e^{-b|\tau|},$$
for all $\tau \in \mathbb R$.

Does it follow that $f=0$?

Answer (score 2):

The expression inside absolute value sign in the LHS is an entire function of $\tau$ (since it can be differentiated under the integral sign and derivative exists for all complex $\tau$).
Your inequality shows that it tends to zero as $\tau\to\infty$
therefore it is zero by Liouville's theorem. Then Fourier inversion says that $f=0$.

To address some comments. The function is entire of exponential type. Since the indicator is negative for $\arg\tau\in(0,\pi)$ is must be $0$ by Phragmen-Lindelof (for all complex $\tau$).

Comment: But why does it tend to zero for non-real $\tau$?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Fragmen-Lindelof. The exponential decay on the line plus the exponential growth outside immediately give an exponential decay in a small angle around the real line, after which everything becomes clear...

Comment: @FedorPetrov I'm more concerned about the "Fourier inversion" part: what Alexandre meant here still escapes me :-(

Comment: @fedja Denote $t^2+it$ by a new variable?

Comment: @FedorPetrov How? it is $\tau$ that runs over the complex plane, not $t$.

Comment: @fedja we get a measure $\mu$ on an arc of parabola such that $\int e^{\tau x} d\mu(x)=0$ for all complex $\tau$. Does not it yield $\mu\equiv 0$?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Yeah, the polynomials (in $z$) are dense on that arc, so you are right: it does.

Comment: @fedja ah, yes, possibly, something like $\exp((t^2+it)/10)$ is even better change of variables in this regard

Comment: @Fedor Petrov I am still puzzled by this “change of variable”. I understand the notion of a complex measure but f is real valued after all. What kind of extension of $f$ is being considered to the complex plane. Recall that f is not analytic afterall.

Comment: @Ali $f(t)dt$ is a measure on $[-1,1]$, after change of variables $h(t)=s$, where $h(t)=\exp(t^2+it)$, you get a pushforward measure  $d\mu$ on the curve $h([-1,1])$, and you get $\int s^\tau d\mu(s)=0$ for all $\tau$

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** I'm undeleting this now, though it may not be of much interest any more. I thought the argument was incomplete, but actually the missing step is quite easy, given a fact about density of polynomials on compact subsets of $\mathbb C$ (Mergelyan's theorem).

Thank you to fedja for pointing this out; see his comments to the linked question.

---

I think I now know how to provide all the details in Alexandre's strategy.

Consider $F(z)=\int f(t)e^{zt^2+izt}\, dt$. This is an entire function of exponential type. Its indicator function $h(\alpha)=\limsup_{r\to\infty} (1/r)\log |F(re^{i\alpha})|$ satisfies $h(0), h(\pi)\le -b$, by assumption. This is impossible for an $F\not\equiv 0$ since always $h(\alpha)+h(\alpha+\pi)\ge 0$ (see, for example, Levin's book for this).

So $F\equiv 0$ and also
$$
F^{(n)}(0) = \int_{-1}^1 f(t) t^n(t+i)^n\, dt = 0
$$
for all $n\ge 0$.
Since $\gamma(t)=t(t+i)$ is injective on $[-1,1]$, this implies that $f=0$.

Comment: Shouldn’t you use the complex version of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem? In that case I am not sure we have a unit algebra here since the conjugation of t(t+i) polynomials are not there