# Uniqueness of a moment style problem

Tags: real-analysis, moments

This is a leftover from [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/425706/on-frequency-decay-of-an-integral-transform-of-a-function/425748#comment1094439_425748) (and I've modified slightly to make the question more natural in the new setting). It's maybe not a very fascinating question by itself, but it seems this is what is missing to answer the linked question, and I'm quite curious about it now.

Let $f\in L^1(-1,1)$ (complex valued), and assume that
$$
\int_{-1}^1 f(x) x^n (x+i)^n\, dx = 0
$$
for all $n\ge 0$. Does this imply that $f=0$ (a.e.)?

Comment: If $f$ is a polynomial of degree $k$, then the assumption for $n=0,\ldots,k$ gives a set of linear equations. For $k$ up to 80, the matrix is non-singular, meaning that $f=0$ if $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most 80. If the matrix is nonsingular always, that would prove it for all polynomials. Would that prove it for all continuous functions?

Comment: @BrendanMcKay: I'm not sure if that follows. If $f$ is arbitrary, you would probably now want to approximate it by polynomials $p_k$, but then it's not clear if the approximation can be done in such a way that $\int p_k x^n(x+i)^n = 0$ also.

Comment: I was only thinking of $\int p_k x^n(x+i)^n\to 0$ for each $n$, but I know it isn't enough. Possibly some bounds on how the matrix norms vary as the degree increases could be useful, but I can't see how to get that.

Comment: Erm... Isn't $x\mapsto x(x+i)$ just a parameterization of an arc of a parabola? And aren't polynomials in $z$ dense in the space of continuous functions with the uniform norm on any Jordan arc? What am I missing?

Comment: @fedja: I didn't know the fact about polynomials on curves, and it confuses me. Doesn't it fail on the unit circle?

Comment: @ChristianRemling Yes, it fails if the compact has inner points and if the complement is not connected. Just look up Mergelyan's theorem. It is much more general than what we need here :-)